# Model-viewer outline

Tags: html, css, model-viewer

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


</head>

<body>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script>
<!-- Use it like any other HTML element -->
<model-viewer src="shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" auto-rotate camera-controls></model-viewer>
</body>

</html>
```

When you click on model viewer the outline appears, I am unable to remove the outline from the `model-viewer` how would one remove it?

[image: When you click on model viewer the outline appears]

Edit

```
/**
 * This is mixin function is designed to be applied to a class that inherits
 * from HTMLElement. It makes it easy for a custom element to coordinate with
 * the :focus-visible polyfill.
 *
 * @param {Function} SuperClass The base class implementation to decorate with
 * implementation that coordinates with the :focus-visible polyfill
 */
export function FocusVisiblePolyfillMixin(SuperClass) {
  var coordinateWithPolyfill = function(instance) {
    // If there is no shadow root, there is no need to coordinate with the
    // polyfill. If we already coordinated with the polyfill, we can skip
    // subsequent invokcations:
    if (
      instance.shadowRoot == null ||
      instance.hasAttribute('data-js-focus-visible')
    ) {
      return;
    }

    // The polyfill might already be loaded. If so, we can apply it to the
    // shadow root immediately:
    if (self.applyFocusVisiblePolyfill) {
      self.applyFocusVisiblePolyfill(instance.shadowRoot);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, wait for the polyfill to be loaded lazily. It might never
      // be loaded, but if it is then we can apply it to the shadow root at
      // the appropriate time by waiting for the ready event:
      self.addEventListener(
        'focus-visible-polyfill-ready',
        function() {
          self.applyFocusVisiblePolyfill(instance.shadowRoot);
        },
        { once: true }
      );
    }
  };

  // IE11 doesn't natively support custom elements or JavaScript class syntax
  // The mixin implementation assumes that the user will take the appropriate
  // steps to support both:
  return class extends SuperClass {
    // Attempt to coordinate with the polyfill when connected to the document:
    connectedCallback() {
      super.connectedCallback && super.connectedCallback();
      coordinateWithPolyfill(this);
    }
  };
}
```

So I added this in file name `focus-visible.js`

added this to html

```
<body>
    <!-- The :focus-visible polyfill removes the focus ring for some input types -->
    <script src="focus-visible.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script>
    <!-- Use it like any other HTML element -->
    <model-viewer src="shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" auto-rotate camera-controls>
    </model-viewer>
</body>
```

and this in css `:focus-visible polyfill{ outline: none; }`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires this script to be added as per model-viewer official documentation

```
<script src="./_model-viewer_ Interactive Example_files/focus-visible.js.download" defer=""></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the focus-visible.js is included in your page. You probably started your modelviewer page with an older example that didn't have it included.

Pick it up from the repo or this link:
https://unpkg.com/focus-visible@5.1.0/dist/focus-visible.js

Answer (score 1):

I add the attribute `data-js-focus-visible` to `<model-viewer>`. Like this:

```
<model-viewer src="myFile.glb" data-js-focus-visible></model-viewer>
```

After that the outline is no longer shown.

If you inspect the `<model-viewer>` component in the main example from the official doc https://modelviewer.dev/ you can see that they use the `data-js-focus-visible` attribute:

```
<model-viewer src="shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" auto-rotate="" camera-controls="" data-js-focus-visible="" ar-status="not-presenting"></model-viewer>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to appear that this is an ongoing issue with `model-viewer` as it is still in development. I would go leave some feedback on their [github page](https://github.com/google/model-viewer), or see if [this issue](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/463) matches yours.

Comment: Yup have read this before, sadly I am not as technically inclined to the point where I understand what they guys are talking about. Funny thing is that on the official website it's not happening https://modelviewer.dev/ ? What are they doing different?

Comment: https://github.com/google/model-viewer/pull/660 So there seems to be resolution here, but I am unsure how to properly implement this.